# Dark mode with checkbox and local storage problem

Tags: angular, typescript

i have a problem with loacl storage, when i activate the dark mode, it works perfectly and the local storage 'dark' is true but when i refresh the page, the local storega is correctly set to true but the toggle and the theme will be back to unchecked and theme white.
for the theme dark i have added boostrap-dark.

app.sample.component.html:

```
  
<div class="form-check form-switch">
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" (change)="toggleDarkTheme()">
<label class="form-check-label" for="flexSwitchCheckDefault">Dark Mode</label>
</div>
```

sample.component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
     import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
     import { ThemeService } from 'src/app/service/theme.service';

     @Component({
       selector: 'app-sample',
       templateUrl: './sample.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./sample.component.css']
     })
     export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
       checked: boolean = false;

       constructor(
         private themeService: ThemeService
       ) {}

       ngOnInit() {
       }

       toggleDarkTheme() {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
         his.themeService.setDarkTheme(this.checked);
         console.log("Dark Theme > ", this.checked);

     }

     }
```

theme.service.ts:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
     import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

     @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
     })
     export class ThemeService {
       constructor() { }

       private _themeDark: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

       isThemeDark = this._themeDark.asObservable();

       setDarkTheme(isThemeDark: boolean) {

         this._themeDark.next(isThemeDark);

         if (isThemeDark == true) {
           console.log('Dark Used');
           document.body.className = 'bootstrap-dark';
           localStorage.setItem('dark', 'true');
         }
         else {
          console.log('Light Used');
           document.body.className = 'bootstrap';
           localStorage.setItem('dark', 'false');
         }

       }



     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read the theme from local storage somewhere. The constructor of your service looks like a good place to do it. I would also suggest to turn this into a `BehaviorSubject` instead, so that new subscribers (observers that subscribe after the `.next` method was called on the subject) also get the latest emitted value:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ThemeService {
  private _themeDark: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;
  public isThemeDark: Observable<boolean>;
  constructor() {
    this._themeDark = new BehaviorSubject(localStorage.getItem("dark") == 'true');
    this.isThemeDark = this._themeDark.asObservable();
    this.setDarkTheme(this._themeDark.value);
  }

  public toggleDarkTheme(): void {
    this.setDarkTheme(!this._themeDark.value);
  }

  // rest of your code here
}
```

In order for your checkbox to reflect the state of the theme observable, you should also bind the `checked` attribute to whatever the observable emits:

```html
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="flexSwitchCheckDefault" (change)="toggleDarkTheme()" [checked]="themeService.isThemeDark | async">
```

And now that we access the `themeService` in the template, we must make it public. The constructor of your `SampleComponent` should then look like this:

```js
  constructor(
    public themeService: ThemeService
  ) {}
```

You should not use the `checked` flag from the component anymore. Leave this logic contained in the service. In your component code, call the `toggleDarkTheme` method from the service instead:

```js
toggleDarkTheme(): void {
  this.themeService.toggleDarkTheme();
}
```

You can also make `setDarkTheme` method inside the service private.

Comment: Property 'isThemeDark' does not exist on type 'ThemeService'. Did you mean '_themeDark'? If i put [checked]="themeService._themeDark| async", and set the _themeDark on public, if the dark on local storage is true the toggle is correctly set to checked but the theme is still white :(

Comment: `isThemeDark` is the public observable that you create out of your private subject. I also updated the code in the answer. Please refresh the page and check again

Comment: @sckami You are right. We should call the `setDarkTheme` to get everything set right.

Comment: so how I have to write it?

Comment: Just like in the answer. Double check it to see if your code still looks like what I posted here because I made some adjustments to it. Especially the service code.

Comment: hi, there is only one problem, when the dark mode is on , when I refresh is still on and thats ok, but if I press the toggle he is still dark, i have to toggle it another time

Comment: That's because you are using at a different boolean property, in your component that is not correctly set. You can create a new method inside the service to handle the whole toggling operation so that everything remains synchronized. I updated the answer to include the necessary changes. Add a new method inside your service `toggleDarkTheme` and call it from the toggle handler inside your component `this.themeService.toggleDarkTheme();`